# put string from calling Activity Method From Inside A Fragment

Tags: android, string, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am calling activity method from Fragment A. Is work fine. 
But how can I put a string, then that opens Fragment B and receive information from the string?

Activity:

```
public void test(){


Send_torrent_url_androidTv_Fragment fragment4 = new Send_torrent_url_androidTv_Fragment();
fragment4.onDestroyView();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction4 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction4.addToBackStack(null);
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
fragmentTransaction4.remove(fragment4);
fragmentTransaction4.replace(R.id.frame,fragment4);
fragmentTransaction4.commit();
```

}

Fragment A:

```
// Listview on item click listener
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                            int position, long id) {
        // getting values from selected ListItem

        final String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString();

        final String id_stream = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_streaming)).getText().toString();

        // Starting single contact activity

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
        builder.setTitle("Select");
        // builder.setMessage("Lorem ipsum dolor ....");
        builder.setItems(new CharSequence[]
                        {getString(R.string.play_video), getString(R.string.remove_video)},
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // The 'which' argument contains the index position
                        // of the selected item
                        switch (which) {
                            case 0:
                                Activity activity = getActivity();
                                if(activity instanceof Main2Activity){
                                    Main2Activity myactivity = (Main2Activity) activity;
                                    myactivity.test();
                                }



                                break;
                            case 1:
                                // Snack Bar
                                Snackbar bar = Snackbar.make(view, R.string.confirm_delete_playlist, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .setAction(R.string.yes, new View.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                                // ---Control remote api---
                                                new Thread() {

                                                    public void run() {

                                                        try {
                                                            HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
                                                            // note : you may also need
                                                            //HttpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)

                                                            HttpURLConnection con =  (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://xxxx/remote/delete-.php?id="+id_stream).openConnection();
                                                            con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                                                            if(con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                                                                //--refresh fragment
                                                                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                                                ft.detach(playlist_torrent.this).attach(playlist_torrent.this).commit();
                                                                //Fin refresh fragment

                                                                // startActivity(getIntent());
                                                                // finish();

                                         /*       final Handler handler = new Handler();
                                                Runnable refresh = new Runnable() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void run() {
                                                        new onPreExecute().execute();
                                                        handler.postDelayed(this, 60 * 1000);
                                                    }
                                                };
                                                handler.postDelayed(refresh, 60 * 1000);     */
                                                            }
                                                            else{

                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        catch (Exception e) {
                                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }.start();
                                                // ----fin Control remote api----
                                            }
                                        });

                                bar.show();


                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

So far everything is going well. But where now place a string bundle?

```
        Send_torrent_url_androidTv_Fragment fragment4 = new Send_torrent_url_androidTv_Fragment();





> Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
>        bundle.putString("token", description);
>        fragment4.setArguments(bundle);




        fragment4.onDestroyView();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction4 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction4.addToBackStack(null);
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        fragmentTransaction4.remove(fragment4);
        fragmentTransaction4.replace(R.id.frame,fragment4);
        fragmentTransaction4.commit();
```

when you put in "test", "description" is a string of Fragment A and not work 
Fragment b:

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
                                String token = args.getString("token");
```

(error).how can you do? thank you

Comment: did you try static method??

Comment: I not put static, I simply just writing this code codes. not use static .

Comment: a simple way is use static keyword for your test method and get string as input parameter  like this : public static test(String string) then inside body of test make new instance of Bundle and.. then add your fragment

Comment: if put static , getSupportFragmentManager() is not work from statis method.

Comment: yes you should get your fragment manager in onCreate of Activity and put it on static FragmentManager field but its not good idea its just a simple way

Comment: And it can solve? or

Comment: In onCreate , It leaves there fragment. Nav view

Comment: Do you want something like public void test(String param), and later use param in the fragments ?

Comment: I added several codes, so you can see better where it comes from and what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `newInstance` to create your fragment, it will be used as constructor with parameters. You can find many [samples in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html).

In your fragment class, create the method

```
public static Send_torrent_url_androidTv_Fragment newInstance(String param) {
        Send_torrent_url_androidTv_Fragment fragment = new Send_torrent_url_androidTv_Fragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("somelabel", param);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
}
```

In every part of your fragment class, you can then access to this value with

```
this.getArguments().getString("somelabel")
```

Then, you can use `activity.test("bazinga")` to pass the value to the fragment, where test is something like this

```
    public void test(String param){
        Send_torrent_url_androidTv_Fragment fragment4 = Send_torrent_url_androidTv_Fragment.newInstance(param);
        //... more code...
    }
```